# ngrx effect call another service based on output from combinelatest

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have the following effect:

```
loadOrganisations$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AdminOrganisationListActions.loadOrganisations),
    switchMap(() => combineLatest(this.adminOrganisationService.list(), this.adminProductService.listProducts()).pipe(
      map(([organisations, products]) => AdminOrganisationListActions.loadOrganisationsSuccess({ organisations, products })),
      catchAppError(error => of(AdminOrganisationListActions.loadOrganisationsFailure({ error })))
    ))
  ));
```

It basically calls 3 end points and passes the results to an action.

I need to modify this effect to allow me to call another service with the results of `this.adminOrganisationService.list()`.

I have tried to create a new map, to enable me to iterate over organizations and call the service for each organization, but its not working correctly.

```
loadOrganisations$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AdminOrganisationListActions.loadOrganisations),
    switchMap(() => combineLatest([
      this.adminOrganisationService.list(),
      this.adminProductService.listProducts(),
      this.adminProductUpgradeService.listProductUpgrades()]).pipe(
      map(([organisations, products, upgrades]) => {
        let features = new Map<number, any>();
        organisations.forEach(o => {
          // Call Service here for each organisation and assign result to features
          this.adminService.getOrganisationAppFeatures(o.id).pipe(map(feature => features.set(o.id, feature))).subscribe();
        })
        return [organisations, products, upgrades, of(features)];
      }),
      map(([organisations, products, upgrades, features]) =>
        AdminOrganisationListActions.loadOrganisationsSuccess({ organisations, products, upgrades })),
      catchAppError(error => of(AdminOrganisationListActions.loadOrganisationsFailure({ error })))
    ))
  ));
```

Update:
The following code works to call the sub service:

```
loadOrganisations$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AdminOrganisationListActions.loadOrganisations),
    switchMap(() => combineLatest([
      this.adminOrganisationService.list().pipe(map( orgs => {
        orgs.map(o =>
          this.adminService.getOrganisationAppFeatures(o.id).pipe(map(feature => {
            return o;
          })).subscribe());
        return orgs;
      })),
      this.adminProductService.listProducts(),
      this.adminProductUpgradeService.listProductUpgrades()]).pipe(
      map(([organisations, products, upgrades]) => {
        return AdminOrganisationListActions.loadOrganisationsSuccess({organisations, products, upgrades});
      }),
      catchAppError(error => of(AdminOrganisationListActions.loadOrganisationsFailure({ error })))
    ))
  ));
```

However, the line `return AdminOrganisationListActions.loadOrganisationsSuccess({organisations, products, upgrades});` is executed before the features for each organization has finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

`combineLatest()` works not as you expect. It will emit *every* time one of the input observables emits, and only after all of them produce a value at least once. If one of them errors, the result of `combineLatest()` also errors.

You are not supposed to use `combineLatest()` in an effect because it takes away the control of when the effect should happen.

You should never subscribe inside an observable.

If you need the results of `adminOrganisationService.list()` before you call another service, then you should do exactly this - call it first.

```
private readonly loadOrganisations = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AdminOrganisationListActions.loadOrganisations),
    switchMap(() => this.adminOrganisationService.list().pipe(
      switchMap((organisations) => forkJoin([
        forkJoin(organisations.map((org) =>
          this.adminService.getOrganisationAppFeatures(org.id).pipe(
            map((features) => ({ orgId: org.id, features }))
          )
        )),
        this.adminProductService.listProducts(),
        this.adminProductUpgradeService.listProductUpgrades(),
      ]).pipe(
        map(([features, products, productUpgrades]) => AdminOrganisationListActions.loadOrganisationsSuccess({
          features,
          organisations,
          products,
          productUpgrades,
        }))
      ))
    ))
  ));
```

Add `catchError()` operators where needed.
Check type of `features` in your IDE.